# Terminator windows snap back to where they were first created

Tags: terminator

This is like the dumbest question ever but I have researched it and can't find any explanation.

I am trying Terminator on Ubuntu 16.04 because of the windows splitting which seems very handy. I am running it in VMWare on Mac. I've gotten it into a weird state. Whenever I create a new Terminator window and the window is placed somewhere on the screen, it seems to be stuck there and if I try moving it elsewhere it snaps back to where it was. It just doesn't want to move.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. Re-enable `Window borders` option via `Preferences` -> `Global`, and restart Terminator. And you should see draggable panel (above title) and resizable window border.
2. If you don't want to re-enable `Window borders`, you can `alt`+`spacebar`, select `Move` and move your mouse to move the window around.

Comment: Thanks, mate :)